# Создание раздела справки про инспекцию кода

Tags: предложение, справка, тематика, инспекция-кода

Ещё в прошлом ноябре мы решили явно включить вопросы про инспекцию кода в допустимую тематику Stack Overflow на русском. На данный момент у нас есть:

- 36 вопросов по метке [инспекция-кода](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%b8%d0%bd%d1%81%d0%bf%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%86%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b0);
- 3 синонима;
- [Краткие указания в описании метки](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/tags/%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B0/info), имеющие аж 25 просмотров;
- Намерение внести дополнение в Справку, высказанное тремя участниками в комментариях.

Давайте это намерение наконец реализуем! Нам нужно:

1. Отредактировать абзац про тематику в разделе «На какие темы здесь можно задавать вопросы?»
2. Написать новый раздел, содержащий требования, рекомендации, пожелания и слова поддержки для авторов, желающих выставить свой код на инспекцию.

---

Полезные ссылки:

- [A guide to Code Review for Stack Overflow users](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5777/73775)

Comment: По сути дело только в том, чтобы создать новую slug-страницу и разрешить редактировать модераторам.

Comment: @Nofate ещё и текст туда нужно придумать. )

Comment: Подскажите, пожалуйста, планируете ли вы выложить что–либо по данной теме?